# If someone says "I am a nazir from grape seeds" according to R' Shimon is he prohibited from grape seeds as a Neder?

Tags: nozir

The Mishna / Gemorah in Nazir 3B says that according to R Shimon if he says I am a Nazir from grape seeds, he is not a Nazir until he specifies everything since he started mentioning details versus if he just said I am a Nazir.

Now since he is not a Nazir, what is his status regarding grape seeds according to R Shimon. Is he prohibited from grape seeds because Nazir is a subset of a Neder and therefor by specifying "I am a Nazir from grape seeds" its like he made a Neder to prohibit grape seeds or is he not prohibited from grape seeds since he did not prohibit it with the language of a Neder?